# Can I use Ubuntu to unlock files locked by a Windows Trojan ( “paytordmdb”)?

Tags: data-recovery

Can I use Ubuntu to break open files that have been locked with “paytordmdb” ?

I use Windows 7 Home version and was attacked by this Trojan.  I was told I cold use Ubuntu to retrieve my files.  Is that true?

Comment: You may wan to post more details on how this malware affected your files. Google does not show anything... make sure there is no typo in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any malicious code written for Windows will have no effect on anything with a Linux Header and Kernel.  When you write code, you must write the code for the platform its intended.  Since the Trojan is meant for Windows, the code wont even activate in a Linux environment.  I would also like to recommend that randomly and blindly downloading anything is dangerous and reckless on a Windows Computer.  If you do download something and it's something your not familiar with, put it in a Virtual Machine and run it.